# Not able to push ios app with watchkit extension to testflight testing

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have made an iOS app with watchkit extension. I am uploading it to itunes connect, it is uploading just fine but when I go to activities page on itunes, it shows me "Invalid Bundle" error and the app is stuck in processing mode. Can someone point out what the issue might be?

Comment: I thought iTunesConnect is on vacation?

Comment: Yes, iTunes is on vacation but testflight internal testing is still open. App submissions have been stopped though for the vacations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after scratching my head for so many days and gathering all the help I could get from the chat rooms, I figured out the problem.
Thing is that when Apple rejects your binary, they email you describing issues with your binary due to which it was rejected, but in my case I had not received any email for quite some time, maybe due to their christmas vacations.

The issue with my binary was something about an alpha channel being present in my watch app icons. Yes you heard it right guys and yes, I am okay right now although I felt like killing myself earlier.
Thanks for all of your help.